# 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm getting the follow error when trying to run my ASP.NET project. Can anyone advise?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Helpers
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Web.Helpers | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = .../.../
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = \...\WebInterface\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: \...\WebInterface\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL /AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/0418a60d/21ffd41/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL /AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/0418a60d/21ffd41/System.Web.Helpers/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL .../.../bin/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: \...\WebInterface\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0 redirected to 3.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL /AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/0418a60d/21ffd41/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL /AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/0418a60d/21ffd41/System.Web.Helpers/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL .../.../bin/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

I've tried the following based on other answers:

- Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 separately from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683
- Updating NuGet packages
- Settings System.Web.Helpers Copy Local to True

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referenced version of System.Web.Helpers assembly in project may not be matching with version mentioned in web.config file. Follow below mentioned steps.

1. Check referenced version of System.Web.Helpers.
2. Check web.config file under root of web application and see if there is entry for System.Web.Helpers and verify its same as that of referenced version.
3. Check web.config file under "Views" folder of web application and see if there is entry for System.Web.Helpers and verify its same as that of referenced version.

Comment: Once you check these, then what do you do? This is not really an answer at all.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem.  It was caused when I added a Razor view to a Web Forms project.  Because of this action, Visual Studio added in .Net Version 5 and made a whole lot of other modifications to the project.

I fixed the problem by going into `Solution Explorer > Pending Changes`.  I observed a whole heap of unusual files listed.  I right-clicked on any of the files and went to `Source Control > Undo Pending Changes`.  I selected the unusual files and `Undo Changes` and after a rebuild it was fixed.

I've seen these extra files get added (for no apparent) reason at other times also.  Some whack-a-doodle thing Visual Studio does for reasons not clear to me.

Comment: This same thing happen to me, created a razor page in a MVC project and the web.config file had added some Systems.Helper tags messing up the build!

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me enormously!

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem when creating a new Razor view. The project was looking for a newer version of the System.Web.Helper and System.Web.WebPages dlls. I solved this issue by editing my web.config and changing the newVersion from 3.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0. You may also be able to remove these entirely from the web.config as I did.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried all of the same things to try to resolve it. None of them worked. I ended up manually copying the dll file from another project. Put it in the project/bin folder. Several of my extensions had this issue, I'm not sure what caused it. [image: File added to /bin folder]

Answer (score -1):

Select the System.Web.Helpers' in solution explorer than in the property panel change the "Copy Local" setting to "False". This works for me.

[image]